# changing the control box on a form when exiting

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok, I have a question about the Form Controlbox. I was wondering if it is possible to change or add what the exit button does on the form.

I can easily minimize, maximize and exit the form no problem. But this is what I am facing.

My app has an access login. After you log in it comes to the main form. I have a log out button when pressed, it goes back to the login form.

However, if you press the exit button, it exits the main form, and the program is still running, but with no way to bring the login form up.

So what I am trying to do is, when the main form is exited through the red X I want it to go to the login.

I can go the complex route: borderless form, movable form, custom buttons and etc., etc.,

I think it would be easier to change or add the exit button to return to the login form. Is this possible?

Comment: There's the FormClosed event that you could hook.

Comment: I was thinking I could do something along the lines as Form States minimize, maximize.. However, the form main exit I figured could be changed.. How would I go about using FormClosed event?

Comment: Just handle the event, and do whatever you do when the logout button is clicked, I guess. You can find the FormClosed event in the designer, form properties, on the events tab. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx

Comment: @Blorgbeard thanks for editing wandering to wondering.. It's been a long day.. Also, per se, is a word meaning "In itself" so when I used per se I was hypothetically saying its complex with in itself... Any way, my app has multiple forms, so would the FormClosed event be for all forms or would I have to do it on each form?

Comment: I am not talking about the log out button.. I am talking about the main form exit (red x). My log out button already does that. I am wanting the red x on the form, when pressed it goes to the login form

Comment: On my main form I have a log out button, when clicked it goes to the login form.

Comment: When do you want the log in button to appear? When the main form closes? When any form is closed? When the last visible form closes? (also, I do know what "per se" means, I just didn't understand what you meant by it in that instance. "Complex in itself", as opposed to..?)

Answer (score 1):

Move the logic out of your button click event, into a separate method.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OverrideFormExit();
}

private void OverrideFormExit()
{
    // execute the code that was previously in button1's click event
}
```

Now you can subscribe that same method to your Form's Closed event, so that it executes when the user closes the Form.

For example, place the following in your Form's constructor:

```
FormClosed += (s, e) => OverrideFormExit();
```

Alternatively, you can subscribe to the main Form's Closed event from within the Login Form, when you instantiate the main Form. I'm guessing at what your code looks like here, obviously.

```
private void ShowMainForm()
{
    FormMain frmMain = new FormMain();
    frmMain.Show();
    frmMain.FormClosed += (s, e) => this.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Grant did you tap into my Visual Studio..lol.. The code is close to what I have.

Comment: My log out button is using .                                                    private void btnlogOut(..)  this.Close();                Login lg = new Login();      lg.Show();                                   I want the main form exit (red x) to do the same

Comment: Ok, when in the main forms design.cs I click on the form and click properties. I then click events.. I am looking at the FormClosed. I click it. I do the code. And it when I debug and test it freezes the form.

Comment: Well my main form is the only one that is going to do it. So I just wanted that one form (frmMain) to go to the login. However I just put the code in and it did not work. It just froze the form.

Comment: Sorry it worked. Like I said long day. I was trying to put this.Close(); in a FormClosed event. It works now. Thanks

Comment: Staring at a 15.6" screen for 12 hours + drinking 3 pots of coffee.. There is bound to be a hiccup sometimes. I am fixing to post another question so just look for it